# Nested comments ef core table model returns all comments?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-model-first

I have blog post model which save comments and replies in same table.

```
public class Comment : Entity, IAggregateRoot
{
    private readonly List<Comment> _replies;

    public Comment()
    {
        _replies = new List<Comment>();
    }

    public string CommentText { get; set; }

    public User User { get; set; }

    public Post Post { get; set; }

    public IReadOnlyList<Comment> Replies => _replies;
}
```

I'm using the following LINQ query to retrieve comments for a specific post.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Comment>> GetCommentsByPostId(Guid postId)
{
    return await Context.Comments
            .AsNoTracking()
            .Include(c => c.Post)
            .Include(c => c.User)
            .Include(c => c.Replies)
            .Where(c => c.Post.Id == postId)
            .ToListAsync();
}
```

The thing is this query returns all the comments, I have tried by adding condition as

```
.Where(c => c.Post.Id == postId && c.Replies.count() == 0)
```

but this returns replies which haven't replies ,

I need to get nested comments hierarchy from the DB.

can anyone help on this

thanks

Comment: Is the self-referencing setup correctly with the entity configuration?

Comment: "returns all the comments" - well, yeah, all comments are associated with a post. Not sure that you're going to be able to get what you're after _directly_ from a query (at least, I gave up trying). It's probably easier to just pre-process the comments before displaying them, to build the tree yourself (plus it's a nice excuse to write recursive methods).